# Error running Linux shell commands in Matlab

Tags: linux, matlab, sh

I am trying to run a shell-script file in Matlab and I get errors of which I have no idea. I am using the `system` command as follows:

```
system('sh path_to_file/file.sh') ;
```

I tried changing permissions

```
chmod -R 755 file
```

and I still can't execute the file. The file runs successfully outside the Matlab script. 
I am running Matlab on Ubuntu 18.04.
I hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Errors:

```
gnuplot: /home/user/Matlab2019a/bin/glnxa64/libQt5Network.so.5: no version information available (required by gnuplot)
gnuplot: /home/user/Matlab2019a/bin/glnxa64/libQt5Core.so.5: no version information available (required by gnuplot)
gnuplot: /home/user/Matlab2019a/bin/glnxa64/libQt5Core.so.5: no version information available (required by gnuplot)
gnuplot: /home/user/Matlab2019a/bin/glnxa64/libQt5Gui.so.5: no version information available (required by gnuplot)
gnuplot: /home/user/Matlab2019a/bin/glnxa64/libtiff.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgd.so.3)
gnuplot: /home/user/Matlab2019a/bin/glnxa64/libtiff.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.so.0)
gnuplot: relocation error: gnuplot: symbol qt_version_tag version Qt_5.9 not defined in file libQt5Core.so.5 with link time reference
```

Comment: What does `which sed` return?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I could run the file, but I still don't solve the errors with gnuplot.

Comment: Do you have necessary environment variables in .bashrc or somewhere? matlab may be unaware of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you cannot run `gnuplot` using MATLAB's shell environment, as paths point to MATLAB's versions of libraries instead of the system's versions. So you need to make sure that the environment is reset.

[One way to do this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48994/how-to-run-a-program-in-a-clean-environment-in-bash) is using `env`:

```matlab
system('env -i sh path_to_file/file.sh')
```

But `sh` doesn't read `.bashrc`, if you set up relevant environment for gnuplot there (not sure this is the case) then you should use `bash` instead of `sh`.

Comment: HI, thanks for your replay. thanks for your response, with the command I could execute gnuplot but now I get the following matlab error: `License checkout failed.
License Manager Error -9
Your username does not match the username in the license file. 
To run on this computer, you must run the Activation client to reactivate your license`

Comment: @Yro: When do you see this message? When running the `system` command? If so, what is the contents of `file.sh`? Do you start MATLAB in that file?

Comment: Yes, when I execute the system command. I am running Matlab from that file also in batch mode. I see another error, for which the file is not executed: `Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused` and `(eog:22394): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:54:00.490: cannot open display:`

Comment: @Yro: Running MATLAB from within MATLAB sounds like a bad idea... In any case, you have some configuration file that sets up information that lets MATLAB find the license file. You need to make sure this one is loaded. If you used `.bashrc`, use `bash` instead of `sh` in your shell command. If this configuration is elsewhere, tell `bash` which configuration files to load (maybe adding the `--login` option, see [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)). Maybe your regular shell is `csh`? Then use that instead of `sh`. Basically, using `sh` is wrong for you because it doesn't load configuration.

Comment: I could solve using the `setenv` command in Matlab-`setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH','/usr/lib')`- . Thanks!